# For classification of quadratic forms with orthogonal diagonalization, why do we need a rotation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I know we can use orthogonal diagonalization to identify the conic
$$5x^2 − 4xy + 8y^2 − 36 = 0$$
by rotating the
$xy$-axes and put it in standard position.

But why do we need a rotation? What happens if we use a reflection instead?

---

**Update:**

For example, consider $x^2 + 2xy+y^2 -3x-5y+4=0$. The matrix
$$
P = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
is a rotation and with it I get the expression: $\sqrt{2}s+ 2t^2=0.$
A parabola.

But if I use
$$
Q = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
a reflection, then I get $2s^2+\sqrt{2}t=0.$ Again, a parabola.

Comment: For both questions I recommend stopping to read the chapter dedicated to quadratic forms in a Linear Algebra textbook. The idea of why we use the rotation transformation is basically caused by the $xy$ factor that you observe in its quadratic form.

Comment: Is it related to the principal axes theorem? I was reading Anton and Rorres' book, but it does not say anything about the rotation. Only it is mentioned when it is applied to classify quadratic forms. Maybe I am missing something. :(

Comment: Of course you can reflect it too - a reflected conic is still a conic (of the same kind), and your conic will have natural reflective symmetries. It depends what you are wanting to do.

Comment: So for classification of conics it does not matter. When should avoid reflection. I can think of a particular context. Any ideas? Thanks :)